# How do I select individual fields in a Dynamic LINQ Select Statement?

Tags: vb.net, linq

I am having what I believe to be syntax issues with my Dynamic LINQ Select Statement, here is my code:

```
  Dim both = (From row1 In AddressListDatatable.AsEnumerable()
            Join row2 In MatrixDatatable.AsEnumerable()
            On row1.Field(Of String)("Offercode") Equals row2.Field(Of 
  String)("Code") Select row1, row2)

 Dim data = both.Select("new (row1.Account, row1.First, row1.OFFERCODE, 
 row2.Expiration, row2.OfferDescription)")
```

This is the Error I am getting: " No property or field 'Account' exists in type 'DataRow' "

So, I believe the issue is in this syntax: **row1.Account, row1.First, etc.**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out. This is the format in which it wanted the fields described as:

```
Dim data = both.Select("new (row1[0] as Account))
```

Answer (score 1):

Did you try?:

var data = both.Select(new {row1.Account, row1.First, row1.OFFERCODE, 
 row2.Expiration, row2.OfferDescription})

Comment: It appears to have syntax issues with the curly brackets... Is that even vb.net?

Comment: Sorry no. I thought it is c#. My fault.

Comment: No worries! Thank you for trying. Do you have the vb.net syntax by chance?

Comment: Sorry - I never used VB :)